# Conditions for applying Ito Isometry

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, isometry, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a question regarding Ito Isometry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry). What conditions do I need for the following statement to hold:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ | \int_0^t K(t,s)\sigma(X_s)dB_s |^2\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t |K(t,s)\sigma(X_s)|^2ds \right].$$
SInce I dont need any martingale property, I should be fine with integrability conditions on $\sigma,K$, is that correct? Or am I getting problems with the adaptedness?
Thx for your help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the adapteness, the Ito integral is define for processes that are adapted. There's an extension that works with non-adapted processes, namely the skorohod integral

Comment: You can see this necessity for adapteness if you start to work with step processes. If the processes are not adapted you can't obtain the Ito isometry (for simple processes) and hence you cannot extend it to general processes

Answer (score 0):

A general Itô is proved here  [Quadratic Variations and the Ito Isometry](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/)

[image]

where you also need predictable as mentioned in the comments.